# How do you set a static IP address on Arch Linux?

Tags: networking, arch-linux

Having read https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration several times, I still find myself struggling with this seemingly simple task.

On one system, I had this working perfectly fine, by having created the file:

```
/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
```

With the following contents:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.200/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

However, note that it uses eth0, and hence only applies settings, to eth0.

After an update and reboot, eth0 is suddenly named enu1u1.

This, being a system without any monitor or keyboard connected, suddenly was impossible to reach.

Now I have a file enu1u1.network and it works again, surviving reboots.

What is the proper way to deal with this? Do I really have to create an udev rule for this? What is the update for the system just overwrites this rule I made, and I'm again back to square one?

I have a very simple setup:

The system has a single, and will always have, a single Ethernet interface.

This is what I want:

I want this Ethernet interface, to always get the IP 192.168.1.200.

How do I do this, and guarantee that it survives updates and reboots?

My idea is to use udev, have plenty of rules to try to match it well, then make the udev rule file immutable to survive updates. However, even then, I don't feel entirely safe. What if some network manager, unknown to me, becomes active, or installed by default, and overrides the static IP by now, wanting to use DHCP?

In short, I feel that setting a static IP is a mess these days. I'm probably just getting old, and abusing the system by not knowing the proper way to do this.

I would like a simple RC file I could edit, and just specify DHCP=no, IP=... and it should just always, work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with v197 `systemd/udev` assigns *"predictable, stable local interface names to all local interfaces"*. See systemd.io posting [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://systemd.io/PREDICTABLE_INTERFACE_NAMES/).

In Arch you can [revert back to traditional interface names](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration#Revert_to_traditional_interface_names) and disable the Predictable Interface Names either by masking the `udev` rule

```
# ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

or adding `net.ifnames=0` to the [kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_parameters).

Answer (score 1):

`enu1u1` is the "predictable" interface name introduced in systemd 197: https://systemd.io/PREDICTABLE_INTERFACE_NAMES/

I would suggest sticking with this new naming, because the old naming scheme (eth0, eth1, ...) was highly dependent on the order that the interfaces were probed by the kernel. Since your concern is surviving updates and reboots, this new predictable name is the way to go (and you've already configured it).

Comment: I fail to see anything wrong with naming the interface eth0 when there is only one interface, and will always only be one interface. The order is irrelevant when there is just one interface. Moreover, eth0 used to be the predictable name, now enu1u1 is the predictable name, but for how long? Ten years, and I'm sure there will be a new "predictable" name.

Comment: Considering systemd 197 is 10 years old and the biosdevname scheme is even older than that, I find it extremely unlikely. However, if you find that changing your network config once every 20 years is too much of an annoyance, systemd might not be the right choice for you.